# Composing BodyParser in Play 2.5

Tags: scala, playframework, akka-stream

Given a function with this signature:

```
def parser[A](otherParser: BodyParser[A]): BodyParser[A]
```

How can I write the function in such a way that the request body is examined and verified before it is passed to `otherParser`?

For simplicity let's say that I want to verify that a header ("Some-Header", perhaps) has a value that matches the body exactly. So if I have this action:

```
def post(): Action(parser(parse.tolerantText)) { request =>
  Ok(request.body)
}
```

When I make a request like `curl -H "Some-Header: hello" -d "hello" http://localhost:9000/post` it should return "hello" in the response body with a status of 200. If my request is `curl -H "Some-Header: hello" -d "hi" http://localhost:9000/post` it should return a 400 with no body.

Here's what I've tried.

This one does not compile because `otherParser(request).through(flow)` expects `flow` to output a `ByteString`. The idea here was that the flow could notify the accumulator whether or not to continue processing via the `Either` output. I'm not sure how to let the accumulator know the status of the previous step.

```
def parser[A](otherParser: BodyParser[A]): BodyParser[A] = BodyParser { request =>
  val flow: Flow[ByteString, Either[Result, ByteString], NotUsed] = Flow[ByteString].map { bytes =>
    if (request.headers.get("Some-Header").contains(bytes.utf8String)) {
      Right(bytes)
    } else {
      Left(BadRequest)
    }
  }

  val acc: Accumulator[ByteString, Either[Result, A]] = otherParser(request)

  // This fails to compile because flow needs to output a ByteString
  acc.through(flow)
}
```

I also attempted to use filter. This one does compile and the response body that gets written is correct. However it always returns a `200 Ok` response status.

```
def parser[A](otherParser: BodyParser[A]): BodyParser[A] = BodyParser { request =>
  val flow: Flow[ByteString, ByteString, akka.NotUsed] = Flow[ByteString].filter { bytes =>
    request.headers.get("Some-Header").contains(bytes.utf8String)
  }

  val acc: Accumulator[ByteString, Either[Result, A]] = otherParser(request)

  acc.through(flow)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with a solution using a `GraphStageWithMaterializedValue`. This concept was borrowed from [Play's `maxLength` body parser](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.12/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/ContentTypes.scala#L672). The key difference between my first attempt in my question (that doesn't compile) is that instead of attempting to mutate the stream I should use the materialized value to convey information about the state of processing. While I had created a `Flow[ByteString, Either[Result, ByteString], NotUsed]` it turns out what I needed was a `Flow[ByteString, ByteString, Future[Boolean]]`.

So with that, my `parser` function ends up looking like this:

```
def parser[A](otherParser: BodyParser[A]): BodyParser[A] = BodyParser { request =>
  val flow: Flow[ByteString, ByteString, Future[Boolean]] = Flow.fromGraph(new BodyValidator(request.headers.get("Some-Header")))

  val parserSink: Sink[ByteString, Future[Either[Result, A]]] = otherParser.apply(request).toSink

  Accumulator(flow.toMat(parserSink) { (statusFuture: Future[Boolean], resultFuture: Future[Either[Result, A]]) =>
    statusFuture.flatMap { success =>
      if (success) {
        resultFuture.map {
          case Left(result) => Left(result)
          case Right(a) => Right(a)
        }
      } else {
        Future.successful(Left(BadRequest))
      }
    }
  })
}
```

The key line is this one:

```
val flow: Flow[ByteString, ByteString, Future[Boolean]] = Flow.fromGraph(new BodyValidator(request.headers.get("Some-Header")))
```

The rest kind of falls into place once you are able to create this flow. Unfortunately `BodyValidator` is pretty verbose and feels somewhat boiler-platey. In any case, it's mostly pretty easy to read. `GraphStageWithMaterializedValue` expects you to implement `def shape: S` (`S` is `FlowShape[ByteString, ByteString]` here) to specify the input type and output type of this graph. It also expects you to imlpement `def createLogicAndMaterializedValue(inheritedAttributes: Attributes): (GraphStageLogic, M)` (`M` is a `Future[Boolean]` here) to define what the graph should actually do. Here's the full code of `BodyValidator` (I'll explain in more detail below):

```
class BodyValidator(expected: Option[String]) extends GraphStageWithMaterializedValue[FlowShape[ByteString, ByteString], Future[Boolean]] {
  val in = Inlet[ByteString]("BodyValidator.in")
  val out = Outlet[ByteString]("BodyValidator.out")

  override def shape: FlowShape[ByteString, ByteString] = FlowShape.of(in, out)

  override def createLogicAndMaterializedValue(inheritedAttributes: Attributes): (GraphStageLogic, Future[Boolean]) = {
    val status = Promise[Boolean]()
    val bodyBuffer = new ByteStringBuilder()

    val logic = new GraphStageLogic(shape) {
      setHandler(out, new OutHandler {
        override def onPull(): Unit = pull(in)
      })

      setHandler(in, new InHandler {
        def onPush(): Unit = {
          val chunk = grab(in)
          bodyBuffer.append(chunk)
          push(out, chunk)
        }

        override def onUpstreamFinish(): Unit = {
          val fullBody = bodyBuffer.result()
          status.success(expected.map(ByteString(_)).contains(fullBody))
          completeStage()
        }

        override def onUpstreamFailure(e: Throwable): Unit = {
          status.failure(e)
          failStage(e)
        }
      })
    }

    (logic, status.future)
  }
}
```

You first want to create an `Inlet` and `Outlet` to set up the inputs and outputs for your graph

```
val in = Inlet[ByteString]("BodyValidator.in")
val out = Outlet[ByteString]("BodyValidator.out")
```

Then you use these to define `shape`.

```
def shape: FlowShape[ByteString, ByteString] = FlowShape.of(in, out)
```

Inside `createLogicAndMaterializedValue` you need to initialize the value you intend to materialze. Here I've used a promise that can be resolved when I have the full data from the stream. I also create a `ByteStringBuilder` to track the data between iterations.

```
val status = Promise[Boolean]()
val bodyBuffer = new ByteStringBuilder()
```

Then I create a `GraphStageLogic` to actually set up what this graph does at each point of processing. Two handler are being set. One is an `InHandler` for dealing with data as it comes from the upstream source. The other is an `OutHandler` for dealing with data to send downstream. There's nothing really interesting in the `OutHandler` so I'll ignore it here besides to say that it is necessary boiler plate in order to avoid an `IllegalStateException`. Three methods are overridden in the `InHandler`: `onPush`, `onUpstreamFinish`, and `onUpstreamFailure`. `onPush` is called when new data is ready from upstream. In this method I simply grab the next chunk of data, write it to `bodyBuffer` and push the data downstream.

```
def onPush(): Unit = {
  val chunk = grab(in)
  bodyBuffer.append(chunk)
  push(out, chunk)
}
```

`onUpstreamFinish` is called when the upstream finishes (surprise). This is where the business logic of comparing the body with the header happens.

```
override def onUpstreamFinish(): Unit = {
  val fullBody = bodyBuffer.result()
  status.success(expected.map(ByteString(_)).contains(fullBody))
  completeStage()
}
```

`onUpstreamFailure` is implemented so that when something goes wrong, I can mark the materialized future as failed as well.

```
override def onUpstreamFailure(e: Throwable): Unit = {
  status.failure(e)
  failStage(e)
}
```

Then I just return the `GraphStageLogic` I've created and `status.future` as a tuple.